# How do I use Prometheus in my business case?

Tags: prometheus

I want to store nearly 2000 machines' metrics and there are 70 metrics of each machine,
and scrape-interval = 10s

so what kind of configuration or performance of my Prometheus server needs at least?

and In that case, how do I make the configuration?

like this:

```
-storage.local.retention=2160h 
-storage.local.memory-chunks=5242880 
-storage.local.max-chunks-to-persist=3097152 
-storage.local.num-fingerprint-mutexes=10240 
-storage.local.series-file-shrink-ratio=0.2 
-storage.local.checkpoint-interval=5m
```

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Best regard!

Answer (score 1):

You can also look into [Prometheus 2.0](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta.5). It is currently in beta with one file format change on the way in the next beta (so you might end up having to drop some historical data at least once) but its storage scales incomparably better and there is nothing to configure for it.

It should be able to handle your expected load without breaking a sweat (famous last words, I know).

Answer (score 0):

Are you having troubles with prometheus keeping up with your current load? I would highly suggest reading this https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/storage/#persistence-urgency-and-rushed-mode and coming back here with a more specific question. Also your retention time will almost surely cause you issues. Prometheus is not meant for long term storage and will likely lead to you entering rushmode and never leaving it causing metric ingestion to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus local storage isn't suited for big retentions. It has the default (recommended) retention - 15 days. Use [remote storage solutions](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/integrations/#remote-endpoints-and-storage) for storing long-term data.